# Neo4j 2.0 + Gremlin + Graphml label support

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, graphml

I am using neo4j 2.0 to store a lot of data. The data massive amount is generated using a ruby script and saved in a graphml file and then imported into neo4j using Gremlin.

```
g.loadGraphML('graphml.xml')
```

With neo4j 2.0, there is a new cool support for labels on a node which I would like to take advantage of. Is it possible to specify which labels a node should have in this way? Or do I really have to make queries afterwards for all nodes, setting their labels.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there is a way, at least within `Blueprints`, which is the interface which Gremlin is built upon. I don't see a way to add a `label` for a `Vertex`, nor do I see anything like that in GraphML.

Perhaps Neo4j will update their code to put the label(s) into a property for a `Vertex` in blueprints, but currently there is no way to get/set the labels using Gremlin/Tinkerpop.

It should also be noted that Blueprints only supports stable versions of Neo4j as we know, so something like 2.0 which is a Milestone wouldn't be fully supported in Blueprints yet.

Comment: I would add that Blueprints only supports Neo4j 1.9.1 at this time (the current stable release).    As far as I know, labels is a 2.0 feature.  Blueprints does not generally depend on milestone releases (which i think is where 2.0 is now).

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I ended up writing a bunch of cypher queries that could add the labels and indexing afterwards.

Comment: That's the best thing to use *for now*. Blueprints may update in the future for this functionality, but right now they don't have it as this is still milestone in Neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Neo4j version 2 you can set a label by getting the underlying Neo4j Node from  the Blueprint Vertex. Note that this breaks the encapsulation and adds a dependence on Neo4j, but this may be required. Also, due to issues with the latest version of Blueprint I'm still not able to use this code properly, but this is how it'd work.

```
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jVertex;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;

// ...

Vertex vertex = graph.addVertex(null);
Neo4jVertex neo4jVertex = (Neo4jVertex) vertex;
Node node = neo4jVertex.getRawVertex();
node.addLabel("SomeLabel");
```